# MySQL - How to search for multiple occurrences of an exact word

Tags: mysql

I wanted to have a query to search a text field for an exact word. I found this query in Stackoverflow and it works great.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_text RLIKE "[[:<:]]beer[[:>:]]";
```

In this query I can find text where the word "beer" appears, but not "beery" or "ambeer", which is what I want. But how do I change my query so that I can search in the product_text field for 2 or 3 occurrences of the word "beer"? That is, I don't want results where the word "beer" appears only once, but where it appears say 3 times.

Comment: you'd have to do something like `/beer.*beer.*(beer)?/`

Comment: Thanks Marc, that should work!